# Detect when Win10 is headless and run BAT file

Tags: automation, headless

I want to launch `"D:\Programmi\usbmmidd(virtual-screen)\$-SCREEN-ADD.bat"` when there are no physical or virtual screens.

I've tried with AutoHotKey, since I already can trigger `run $-SCREEN-ADD.BAT` with a hotkey.

This is what I have. (I don't need the automation to use AHK, it's just what I'm most familiar with.)

```
OnMessage(0x219, "MsgMonitor")
MsgMonitor(wParam, lParam, msg)
{
SysGet, MonitorCount, MonitorCount
if (MonitorCount<1) {
   run "D:\Programmi\usbmmidd(virtual-screen)\$-SCREEN-ADD.bat"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WORKING SOLUTION**:

```
; ►►►►►►►►►►►►►►    ◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄
OnMessage(0x219, "MsgMonitor")
MsgMonitor(wParam, lParam, msg)
{
   SysGet, MonCount, MonitorCount      ;► num of screens
   SysGet, W1, 78           ;► width  of all the screens
   SysGet, H1, 79           ;► height of all the screens
   if (MonCount=1 and W1=640 and H1=480) {
      run "D:\Programmi\usbmmidd(virtual-screen)\$-SCREEN-ADD.bat"
   }
}
; ►►►►►►►►►►►►►►    ◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄◄

; PUT HERE YOUR OTHER SCRIPTS IF NEEDED
```

**DESCRIPTION**: the script runs with any change in hardware. It adds a virtual screen (by running $-SCREEN-ADD.bat) whenever it detects only 1 screen with a resolution of 640x480, which is what Windows thinks it has when it has no physical or virtual monitors connected.

**NOTE**: this script has to be in the top of the file, which is the [auto-execute portion](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto). More info on the script in [this thread on the AutoHotKey forum](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).